# Associated belongs with qor admin

Tags: go, qor

I have these two structures:

```
type Collection struct {
    gorm.Model
    APIKey       string
    CollectionID string
    Name         string
    Environments []Environment
}
type Environment struct {
    gorm.Model
    EnvironmentID string
    Name          string
    Provider      string
    FlightType    string
    ADT           int
    CHD           int
    INF           int
}
```

And the main looks like:

```
func main() {
    adminResource := admin.New(&admin.AdminConfig{DB: model.DB})
    adminResource.AddResource(&model.Collection{})
    adminResource.AddResource(&model.Environment{})

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    adminResource.MountTo("/admin", mux)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mux); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Listening on: 8000")
    }
}
```

The point is that I don´t know if I should to do something else to allow the membership relationship one-to-many between the Collection and the Environemt. The thing is that the form on the admin view looks good, I can add as many environments as I was... but submitting the form **only the `Collection` are saved on the database**.

Comment: Did you set any relations between your two models? https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#Relationship

Comment: Hi @apxp I was trying to do this: `db.Model(&Collection).Related(&Environment)`. I tried to use the structs of Collection and Environments as arguments, but these functions are oriented to the instance. And **I don´t know where to do that**, because the handling of the forms is managed internally by the qor. Is there any way to add a middleware (or something) on the Collection´s load??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

```
type Collection struct {
    gorm.Model
    APIKey       string
    CollectionID string
    Name         string
    Environments []Environment
}
type Environment struct {
    gorm.Model
    EnvironmentID string
    Name          string
    Provider      string
    FlightType    string
    ADT           int
    CHD           int
    INF           int
    CollectionID  int
}
```

Adding `CollectionID  int` on the Environment struct is enough... so simply :D.

Thanks @apxp

Answer (score 1):

The thing, which is missing is to tell gorm the foreign key of the other model.

In your case we use [Has Many (gorm Doc)](http://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html). To define the relationship you have to add a tag to your struct:

```
type Collection struct {
    gorm.Model
    APIKey       string
    CollectionID string
    Name         string
    Environments []Environment `gorm:"foreignkey:EnvironmentID"`
}
type Environment struct {
    gorm.Model
    EnvironmentID string
    Name          string
    Provider      string
    FlightType    string
    ADT           int
    CHD           int
    INF           int
}
```

Without defining the foreign key of the other model gorm is not able to match those both models. As the [convention](http://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html) for the primary key is `ID` and your `Enviroment` does not have that field it is not possible to match something. Be sure to read the documentation about the [conventions](http://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html).

Comment: Hi again @apxp It seems that starts to work... but I found a pair of new problems: 
1) The admin doesn´t allow edit the EnvironmentID (and it is needed). The solution: `Environments []Environment \`gorm:"foreignkey:ID"\``.
2) This solution generates a new problem: Only the last Environment is saved on the DB, trying to add a new one, this last edits the previous, instead insert a new env.
3) I try to do this (on the env struct): `ID uint \`gorm:"primary_key" sql:"AUTO_INCREMENT"\`` But adding more than env I get: _pq: duplicate key violates uniqueness restriction «environments_pkey»_